# "Web deployment task failed" error in asp.net MVC project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0

I have a asp.net mvc project which I am trying to run on VS2013.Though it builds successfully it always gives the below error while running it.

> "Web deployment task failed. (Unknown
>   ProviderOption:DefiningProjectFullPath. Known ProviderOptions
>   are:skipInvalid.)"

Any suggestions on how to fix this issue ? I didn't see anything in the event viewer. I followed some queries on stackoverflow related to this issue, but none of them helped me.

I have no clue why this error comes and how to fix it..I am running the web project in my local IIS.

Comment: Where are you deploying to? Azure?

Comment: I am deploying it to Local IIS.

Comment: is the ms deploy installed?

Comment: Yes, I have installed it.

Answer (score 0):

We had the same problem on our build servers.
Visual Studio 2013 Premium Update 1 was installed there.

After I've **upgraded to VS 2013 Update 2 RC** everything worked as before. It comes with a go-live license and you'll be able to update to the RTM, when it's released.

I've got the hint in this comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bharry/archive/2014/04/02/tfs-2013-2-update-2-released.aspx#10515773